# AttributeError: __enter__ dearpygui tabs

Tags: python, python-3.x, dearpygui

i was trying to use tabs in dearpygui and it gives me
this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\main.py", line x, in <module>
    with dpg.add_tab_bar():
AttributeError: __enter__
```

i tried to do it like this

```
dpg.add_tab_bar('tabbar')

dpg.add_tab('tab1')
dpg.add_checkbox(label='checkbox')
dpg.end_tab()

dpg.end_tab_bar()
```

id didnt work to 
 
the code:

```
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

with dpg.window(label="window") as mainwind:
    with dpg.add_tab_bar():
        with dpg.add_tab(label='tab1'):
            dpg.add_checkbox(label='checkbox')
        


dpg.start_dearpygui()
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `with dpg.add_tab_bar():` to just `dpg.add_tab_bar()`?

Comment: Right.  An object has to have specific support for the `with` statement, and these objects don't.  Just do normal assignments/calls.

Comment: mkrieger1, yes i have tried but it does not work to `dpg.add_tab_bar('tabbar')
TypeError: add_tab_bar() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: this is differnt problem - `add_tab_bar()` can't get positional value. Maybe you have to use named value - ie.  `label="tabbar"` - You should check it in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I digg in source code of [demo](https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/blob/master/DearPyGui/dearpygui/demo.py) and you simply mix different methods.

If you use `with` then use function **WITHOUT** `add_`

```
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

with dpg.window(label="window"):       # without `add_`
    with dpg.tab_bar(label='tabbar'):  # without `add_`
        with dpg.tab(label='tab1'):    # without `add_`
            dpg.add_checkbox(label='Hello')
        with dpg.tab(label='tab2'):    # without `add_`
            dpg.add_checkbox(label='World')

dpg.start_dearpygui()
```

And the same without `with` but it needs `add_` and `parent=`

```
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

window = dpg.add_window(label="window")

tabbar = dpg.add_tab_bar(label='tabbar', parent=window)

tab1 = dpg.add_tab(label='tab1', parent=tabbar)
dpg.add_checkbox(label='Hello', parent=tab1)

tab2 = dpg.add_tab(label='tab2', parent=tabbar)
dpg.add_checkbox(label='World', parent=tab2)

dpg.start_dearpygui()
```

And mix of both methods

```
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

with dpg.window(label="window"):       # without `add_`
   
    tabbar = dpg.add_tab_bar(label='tabbar')  # without `parent`
    
    tab1 = dpg.add_tab(label='tab1', parent=tabbar)
    dpg.add_checkbox(label='Hello', parent=tab1)
    
    tab2 = dpg.add_tab(label='tab2', parent=tabbar)
    dpg.add_checkbox(label='World', parent=tab2)

dpg.start_dearpygui()
```

If you use `with ... as name:` then you can use `name` as `parent` but you may also skip it.

```
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

with dpg.window(label="window") as window:       # without `add_`
   
    #tabbar = dpg.add_tab_bar(label='tabbar')                 # without `parent`
    tabbar = dpg.add_tab_bar(label='tabbar', parent=window)   # or with `parent`
    
    tab1 = dpg.add_tab(label='tab1', parent=tabbar)
    dpg.add_checkbox(label='Hello', parent=tab1)
    
    tab2 = dpg.add_tab(label='tab2', parent=tabbar)
    dpg.add_checkbox(label='World', parent=tab2)

dpg.start_dearpygui()
```

---

**BTW:** and text you have to always use with `label=`